# Hide log4j logs

Tags: log4j

I'm using log4j to display the logs...

I'm using an xml configuration and here is the log4j.xml I'm using :

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="stderr" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="warn" />
        <param name="target" value="System.err"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <param name="target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="debug" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="info" />
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="ERROR"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="stderr" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

When I'm executing a main class, I want to have in my console the Error logs only .. However Log4j still display it's log :

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@72ea2f77.
log4j: Using URL [file:/Users/***/jpa-model/target/classes/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "false".
```

Is there a possibility that I hide the log4j logs ?

I have tried to initiate the logger my self and to set the level to OFF but log4j still display its proper logs :

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernateTest.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Thank you

Comment: Its been a while since I've used log4j, but I think you can just modify the filter tag to have the min and max levels set to error.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried what you said and I got the same result ... do you suggest another logger system ?

Comment: this logs you refer to are not log4j loggers, but the log4j logging itseld to system.out when initializing (searching for log4j.xml and the like). If I remember correctly this is due toma debug argument passed when running the program, is that so?

Comment: Yes it is the log4j logging ... and no I am not using tomcat ... I'm using Hibernate ... by the way I'm not passing any argument to my main class

Comment: It was a typo, I didnt meant tomcat, I meant "to an" :/ so does this really bother you? because those logs will only appear once, when your program starts and the log4j system is initialized. From then, the log4j system takes over and your configuration will take place, debugging only as you need.

Comment: @jotadepicas... it really dont bother me :) ... I'm new using log4j and in my mind it is like if I can control every log output :) .. so I'm seeking the perfect result ... and you know .. when something dosent do as we like we will not feel comfortable (in programming) .... So I really can surpass this ...

Comment: I see :P, but there is something conceptual here. You cannot use log4j to control the logging log4j ITSELF does while it self initializes. That goes to standard output, because log4j is not ready. So if you want to control that, you have to look for whatever your system is using to log PRIOR to log4j being initilized. (unless im very wrong here... :/ )

Comment: Thank you for the analysis ... I agree with you .. It doesnt make sens what I m trying todo ... Goood , I ve learned something ... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me:

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-6p [%c] %m%n
log4j.appender.console.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.console.filter.1.StringToMatch=Artifact
log4j.appender.console.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.console.filter.2=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```